# JavaFX tree/tableView row column width is not same as header column width

Tags: javafx-8, column-width, treetableview, jxtreetable

When I fill table tree/tableview with programmatically table row width column is not same table column header with. But after any action inside table (such scrool or click any cell)everything is ok. To understand the problem please look the below pictures

[image: Load table first time]

[image: after any action in the table]

Comment: That's weird, but calling `TableView#layout` after setting the items would probably solve it...

Comment: does not work. Result is same

Comment: Could you share the code used to initialize the table and the code used to add data?

Comment: Ok let me make simple app to produce this error

Comment: I make simple app using the same code. But everything is ok. i have lots of view on my original soft may be because of this.